# Moving from laravel 6 to 7x getting this error, arcanedev/laravel-messenger 7.2.0 requires arcanedev/support ^5.1

Tags: laravel, laravel-6.2, laravel-7, laravel-upgrade

Moving from laravel 6 to 7x  getting this error,    arcanedev/laravel-messenger 7.2.0 requires arcanedev/support ^5.1

[This is the error while i run composer update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbt5U.png)

*This is composer.json file*

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"type": "project",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": [
    "framework",
    "laravel"
],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.2.5",
    "arcanedev/laravel-messenger": "7.2",
    "cboden/ratchet": "^0.4.2",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
    "intervention/image": "^2.4",
    "laravel/cashier": "^10.5",
    "laravel/framework": "7.0.*",
    "laravel/nexmo-notification-channel": "^2.3",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
    "php-imap/php-imap": "^4.1",
    "pusher/pusher-php-server": "^4.0",
    "spatie/laravel-permission": "^3.13.0",
    "twilio/sdk": "^6.6",
    "webklex/laravel-imap": "^1.4"
},
"require-dev": {
    "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
    "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
    "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
    "laravel/ui": "^2.0.0",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.1",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5"
},
```

*I can not post complete Composer.json file here getting this error while i posting my question, so i attached another screenshot of my composer.json file*
[screenshot of my composer.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2sMx.png)

> Can anyone help me out? Thank you!

Comment: `arcanedev/laravel-messenger` does [not support](https://github.com/ARCANEDEV/LaravelMessenger#features) Laravel 7

Comment: try to install `composer require arcanedev/support` first it should works

Comment: @Clément Baconnier  then what can be a batter solution, should i use alternate of  arcanedev/laravel-messenger ?

Comment: @Joseph when i run this  ** composer require arcanedev/support **, i am getting this error  `arcanedev/laravel-messenger 7.2.0 requires arcanedev/support ^5.1 -> satisfiable by arcanedev/support[5.1.0, 5.1.1, 5.2.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
 `

Comment: try to specify the version like this it may fix it `composer requires arcanedev/support:5.1`

Comment: I would suggest to make a pull request or open a github issue.

Comment: @Joseph `arcanedev/support` does [not support](https://github.com/ARCANEDEV/Support/blob/5.1.0/composer.json) Laravel 7 either.  Version 7 of  `arcanedev/support` does support Laravel 7 though. That's why I would recommend a pull request to tag laravel-messenger with a new version